# Sitecore 9.0 update 1 and Solr version

Tags: solr

I noticed slight differences in the Solr version for Sitecore 9 update 1. [Here](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897) 6.6.1 is mentioned whereas the installation guide has 6.6.2. Does the initial 9 release need 6.6.1 and update 1 requires 6.6.2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use SOLR 6.6.1 due to a Solr Bug that has been identified.

Use SOLR 6.6.2, which is the recommended version.  The KB article has not been updated to reflect this except in footnote:

> Solr server can try to initialize a Solr core twice, resulting in the
>   following error:

```
> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core
> [core_name] ... Caused by:
> org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this
> virtual machine:
> C:\solr-6.6.1\server\solr\core_name\data\index\write.lock The error is
> caused by a Solr bug: SOLR-11297
```

> The issue does not affect Sitecore functionality and can be ignored.
>   To resolve the issue, upgrade Solr to 6.6.2.

Comment: Is there anything written in the Sitecore specs about getting the recommended Solr version to a non dead version or LTS version?

Comment: Nothing written in docs. Lots of folks have had no problem using the LTS version.